# Sub-dots in python classes

Tags: python, class

I am using a python package that lets me do something like:

```
korea = country()
korea.food.kimchi()
```

Somehow, using the dot notation, I'm able to go more than one dot deep in the class. I tried looking in the code for the 'country' class, but I could see where the '.kimchi' came from. I understand how it's done with functions (using sub-directories) but not with classes like this.

I'm a little new to classes, but if anyone could tell me / give an example / suggest some good key-words to type into yahoo, then that would be really helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a ton of ways you could do it. One would be:

```
class Food(object):
    def kimchi(self):
        return 'mmm'

class country(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.food = Food()
```

You're just getting attributes, so to make a "sub dot", make sure that the attribute that you're accessing has attributes as well.

Comment: Thanks! I'll use this method.